# Append error message on jTextArea with different color

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextarea

I was wondering if there is a way to append an error message in a `jTextArea` with different font color.

Like this it will make a difference between the normal output that I am appending and the error output.

For example, on Netbeans the `system.err` font color is red, and the `System.out` is appearing black.

Comment: JTextArea is not capable of this behaviour. Use JTextPane instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`JTextArea` only allows a single color to be used. You can use a [`JTextPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html) instead

Comment: Thank you very much , your solution will do the job :)

Answer (score 3):

Two Swing classes support styled text: JEditorPane and its subclass JTextPane. The JEditorPane class is the foundation for Swing's styled text components and provides a mechanism through which you can add support for custom text formats.

If you want unstyled text, use a text area instead.

Source :[Styling Dynamically](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html#textpane)

Answer (score 0):

I afraid it is not possible to display colored text in jtextarea. you can only do that on jtextpane and [here how](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/message-console/) .